# how to find length of RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

How can i find the length of the below RDD?

```
var mark = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))

scala> mark.map(l => l.length).collect
<console>:27: error: value length is not a member of Int
   mark.map(l => l.length).collect
```

Comment: if i use sc.textFile ,its working, when i use sc.parallelize not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should clarify what you want exactly. In your examplek you are running a map function, so it looks like you are trying to get the length of each of the fields of the RDD, not the RDD size.

`sc.textFile` loads everything as `Strings`, so you can call length method on each of the fields. Paralellize is parallelizing the information as Ints because your list is made of integers.

If you want the size of an RDD you should run count on the RDD, not on on each field

```
mark.count()
```

This will return 6

If you want the size of each element you can convert them to `String` if needed, but it looks like a weird requirement. It will be something like this:

```
mark.map(l => l.toString.length).collect
```